# Better way to trigger a sound from viewModel code to Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewmodel

So I am working on my first viewModel app, it needs to make a sound with something like ...

```
MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.app_start).start()
```

But this requires context, if I understand correctly context should not be referenced by the viewModel code to avoid memory leaks so I need my fragment to execute the code.

To trigger the sound in the fragment from the viewModel code I could define a state observer on a boolean and flip its state in the viewModel to execute the code in the fragment but this seems messy as I would have to flip it twice to make it ready for the next need for a sound.

Is there a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. Well, using an observable you have just hit the classic "observe an event" problem.
Standard Google observables usage is for a value (state), and as you have noticed, you have a problem with needing to "reset" the value (publishing the same value doesn't notify the observers).

There are lots of ways around this, but depending on your need, a quick (actually a bit hacky IMHO) solution is to use a timestamp (maybe a millisecond time value) as the trigger.
Every time you push the value, it will be different so will be observed in the fragment.

In most cases like this, you don't really care about the value, it's just a trigger .. in this case to play a sound.. but it could just as easily be to exit the fragment, or something else.